# Boost Intrusive Swap

Tags: c++, boost, intrusive-containers, boost-intrusive

I have a class declared as `class MyClass : public list_base_hook<link_mode<normal_link>>`. I also have a list declared as `list<MyClass> global_list_MyClass`.

I insert 10 nodes into `global_list_MyClass` using a for loop. My objective is try to swap `Node1` and `Node2` using `boost::intrusive::swap` but seems like failed (a lot of compilation error).

I tried to search around internet but can't find any good example for this.

Example code:

```
class MyClass : public list_base_hook<link_mode<normal_link>>
{
public:
   int nValue;

public:
    MyClass(){}
    virtual ~MyClass(){}
};
static boost::intrusive::list<MyClass> global_list_MyClass;


//Insert 10 nodes
for (int n=0; n<10; n++)
{
  MyClass *p_oTMP1 = new MyClass();
  p_oTMP1->nValue = n;
  global_list_MyClass.push_back(*p_oTMP1);
}


//Search for Target node 1
int nTarget1 = 5;
boost::intrusive::list<MyClass>::iterator oTmpTarget1;
for (list<MyClass>::iterator iTmpToken=global_list_MyClass.begin();     iTmpToken!=global_list_MyClass.end(); iTmpToken++)
{
  if (!(iTmpToken->nValue == nTarget1))
    continue;
  oTmpTarget1 = iTmpToken;
  break;
}


//Search for Target node 2
int nTarget2 = 6;
boost::intrusive::list<MyClass>::iterator oTmpTarget2;
for (list<MyClass>::iterator iTmpToken=global_list_MyClass.begin(); iTmpToken!=global_list_MyClass.end(); iTmpToken++)
{
  if (!(iTmpToken->nValue == nTarget2))
    continue;
  oTmpTarget2 = iTmpToken;
  break;
}


//Swap Node1 with Node2
/*Here is what i not sure what to do with boost::intrusive::swap or     global_list_MyClass.swap()
```

Comment: Show your compilation errors. We can't fix something we can't see.

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball's currently out of order. You'll have to give us more information - such as a minimal code sample (or even better an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)), and the compilation errors.

Comment: And don't add thanks to the question again, Angew removed them because they are nothing but noise.

Comment: As for the "thanks" thing, it's [a site policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/201677) (see also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97137/201677)).

Comment: Ok noted, sorry this is my first post to stackoverflow.com

Comment: No problem at all. If only all first-time posters reacted this well to comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `swap()` here - that's for swapping containers, not nodes within containers. You can remove the elements and re-insert them at the swapped locations, though:

```
void swapItems(boost::intrusive::list<MyClass> &list, boost::intrusive::list<MyClass>::iterator it1, boost::intrusive::list<MyClass>::iterator it2)
{
  if (it1 == it2) return;
  MyClass &node1 = *it1;
  MyClass &node2 = *it2;
  it1 = list.erase(it1);
  if (it1 == it2) {  //1 was immediately followed by 2
    list.insert(++it2, node1);
    return;
  }
  it2 = list.erase(it2);
  list.insert(it2, node1);
  list.insert(it1, *node2);
}
```

Of course, writing this function as tailored to `MyClass` is almost absurd - it would be much better served as a function template to work with an arbitrary class. It could perhaps even templated by container type, but you'd have to be more careful there with regard to iterator invalidation.

An alternative would be to provide something like a `swapValues()` function in your class anc call that:

```
void MyClass:swapValues(MyClass &other)
{
  using std::swap;
  swap(nValue, other.nvalue);
  //dtto for other members, but NOT for the boost::intrusive linking structure
}
```

Comment: Some error at "MyClass *node1 = *it1;". Error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'MyClass' to 'MyClass *'

Comment: @Jimmy Sorry, fixed. I've never used Boost.Intrusive, so I am not familiar with the interface details.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. There is a way to convert iterator back to its orignal class. i need to find it further...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! It is working now... some typo mistake earlier.

Comment: I found 2nd option... not sure it is good enough or not "oTmpTarget1->swap_nodes(*oTmpTarget2);"

Comment: @Jimmy As I said, I've never used Boost.Intrusive. I assume the docs will tell you whether `swap_nodes()` is intended as part of the public interface, and what exactly it does.